# json comparison with in the object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, json

I have got sample json object has format like this below ..

```
var result =  [{"value":"S900_Aru","family":"S400"},
              {"value":"S500_Aru","family":"S400"},
              {"value":"2610_H","family":"A650"}]
```

if you see first two **values** are related to same family and the third one is belongs to other **family** ...

How can i loop through this complete json object and i need to alert the customer saying that these three are not related to same family ...

Would any one please help on this issue..
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/Array/every):

```
var test = result.every(function(item, index, array){
  return item.family === array[0].family;
}); // true if all items in array have same family property set
```

```js
var result =  [{"value":"S900_Aru","family":"S400"},
              {"value":"S500_Aru","family":"S400"},
              {"value":"2610_H","family":"A650"}];
              
var test = result.every(function(item, index, array){
  return item.family === array[0].family;
});

alert(test);
```

Comment: @A.Wolff   Enigma is expecting a statement like `alert((test)?"Related to the same family":"Not related to the same family");`

Comment: @Thanga `if(test){alert("Related to the same family"} else {alert("Not related to the same family");}`. If it is, i was thinking it was really obvious

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop with comparisons will do.

```
for (var i= 1, first = result[0].family; i< result.length; i++) {
  if (result[i].family !== first) {
    alert('Family mismatch')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
var jsonString = '[{"value":"S900_Aru","family":"S400"},{"value":"S500_Aru","family":"S400"},{"value":"2610_H","family":"A650"}]';
var jsonData = $.parseJSON(jsonString);

var valueArray = new Array();
$.each(jsonData, function (index, value) {
    valueArray.push(value['value']);
    if ($.inArray(value['value'], valueArray)) {
        alert('Duplicate Item');
        return;
    } else {
        // Continue
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var result =  [{"value":"S900_Aru","family":"S400"},
              {"value":"S500_Aru","family":"S400"},
              {"value":"2610_H","family":"A650"}]

var itemFamily = result[0].family;
var differs = false;
result.forEach(function(itm){ 
 if (itemFamily != itm.family) { 
   differs = true;
 } 
});

alert((differs)?"Not related to the same family":"Related to the same family");
```

Answer (score 1):

I will store the first value of `family` and use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/every) to check for every elements of the array.

```
value  = result[0].family;

function isSameFamily(element) {
  return element.family == value;
}

a = result.every(isSameFamily);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ejd64es0/

```
if(a){
 alert("Same family")
}
else{
  alert("Not Same family")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two for loops to check each object with each other object and log the message when two families don't match.

```
for(var i=0;i<result.length-1;i++) {
    for(var j=1;j<result.length;j++) {
        if(result[i].family !== result[j].family)
            console.log("Families do not match");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check every element with the first element and return the result of [`Array#every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
var result = [{ "value": "S900_Aru", "family": "S400" }, { "value": "S500_Aru", "family": "S400" }, { "value": "2610_H", "family": "A650" }],
    related = result.every(function (a, i, aa) {
        return aa[0] === a;
    });

document.write(related);
```